# Error : could not start the command : pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode

Tags: compiling, ubuntu

I have Ubuntu 14.04 , and a `Texmaker`. Trying to to compile:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\begin{document}
s
\end{document}
```

if i compile this file, the following  error appears:

`Error : could not start the command : pdflatex -synctex=1
 -interaction=nonstopmode`

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Welcome, you have to install [TeX Live](http://tug.org/texlive/)

Comment: you can do `pdflatex --version` to know if it exits or to know the version. In the former, just install it and then it should work like a charm.